# UITextField resizing in viewDidLoad Method

Tags: ios, resize, uitextfield, viewdidload

Im working on an app that has a series of UItextFields for data entry, i wanted them to dynamically space themselves on the screen depending on the device type, and it works well, however the UITextFields have been narrowed and i can't make them stay the width they originally were. the textfields were added to the view in the storyboard and were 130x31.
after the add subview for loop at the bottom they are approximately 31 pixels wide.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // for debugging
    NSLog(@"opsToolsSevenHundred view did load");

    // Spaces the text fields labels and buttons in the view
    int i =0;

    NSArray *viewSubViews = [self.view subviews];
    for (i=0; i<[viewSubViews count]; i++) {
        [[viewSubViews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
    };



    float numberOfFields = 10;
    float alignmentCount = numberOfFields+1;
    float textFieldCenter = (self.view.frame.size.width/4)*3;
    float topFourLabelCenter = ((self.view.frame.size.width/7)*3);
    float bottomSixLabelCenter = ((self.view.frame.size.width/3));
    float buttonCenter = (self.view.frame.size.width/6);
    float navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    float verticleSpacingOffset = (self.view.frame.size.height - navBarHeight)/alignmentCount;
    self.oneTextField.center = CGPointMake (textFieldCenter, (verticleSpacingOffset + navBarHeight
    self.twoTextField.center = CGPointMake(textFieldCenter, (verticleSpacingOffset*2) + navBarHeight);
    self.threeTextField.center = CGPointMake(textFieldCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*3)+navBarHeight));
    self.fourTextField.center = CGPointMake(textFieldCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*4) + navBarHeight));
    self.fiveTextField.center = CGPointMake(textFieldCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*5) + navBarHeight));
    self.sixTextField.center = CGPointMake(textFieldCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*6) + navBarHeight));
    self.sevenTextField.center = CGPointMake(textFieldCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*7) + navBarHeight));
    self.eightTextField.center   = CGPointMake(textFieldCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*8) + navBarHeight));
    self.nineTextField.center = CGPointMake(textFieldCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*9) + navBarHeight));
    self.tenTextField.center = CGPointMake(textFieldCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*10) + navBarHeight));
    self.oneLabel.center  = CGPointMake(topFourLabelCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset) + navBarHeight));
    self.twoCountLabel.center  = CGPointMake(topFourLabelCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*2) + navBarHeight));
    self.threeLoadLabel.center = CGPointMake(topFourLabelCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*3) + navBarHeight));
    self.fourLabel.center = CGPointMake(topFourLabelCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*4) + navBarHeight));
    self.fiveLabel.center = CGPointMake(bottomSixLabelCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*5) + navBarHeight));
    self.sixLabel.center = CGPointMake(bottomSixLabelCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*6) + navBarHeight));
    self.sevenLabel.center = CGPointMake(bottomSixLabelCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*7) + navBarHeight));
    self.eightLabel.center = CGPointMake(bottomSixLabelCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*8) + navBarHeight));
    self.nineLabel.center = CGPointMake(bottomSixLabelCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*9) + navBarHeight));
    self.tenLabel.center = CGPointMake(bottomSixLabelCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*10) + navBarHeight));
    self.oneButton.center = CGPointMake(buttonCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*1.5)+navBarHeight));
    self.twoButton.center = CGPointMake(buttonCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*2.5)+navBarHeight));
    self.threeButton.center = CGPointMake(buttonCenter, ((verticleSpacingOffset*3.5)+navBarHeight));

    i=0;

    for (i=0; i<[viewSubViews count]; i++) {
        [self.view addSubview:[viewSubViews objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not try auto layout ?

Comment: You should use the `viewWillLayoutSubview` method to layout the subviews. And why do you remove all of the subviews then add them all back?

Comment: i removed them and add them back to force the objects to redraw in the new position.  I tried the auto layout but it wasn't working for me i found it harder to line them up the way i wanted them

Comment: You do not need to remove and add to move them. Simply update the center or frame. Make sure you don't have auto layout or constraints setup if you plan to manually position the views.

Comment: i changed the placeholder text to 6 characters, and they're all the same size now and sufficient for what i need, but i still don't understand why they're being resized when i move them, nothing in my code is changing the sizes.